# How best to find literature on motion graphics design

Tags: recommendation, motion

I'm looking for material on motion graphics; books, video tutorials, etc. I think I don't just need to check out "advanced" stuff, but also the very basics. (Since there's always much you can learn there).

What techniques would be best to find relevant and current material?

Comment: Hey Zettt, Vimeo has just release the 2012 awards short lists and one of the categories is Motion Graphics, including one on "A History of the Title Sequence" and another "The Fundemental Elements of Design" which is a great way to see what is current. There are a dozen on this page: https://vimeo.com/awards/vote/motiongraphics

Comment: I would say that since things change so much in the field of Motion Graphics as it is heavily technology driven, a book may already be out of date. The field is definitely a "moving target". :>

Comment: Thanks filzilla, I'm going to watch these later.  Unfortunately that's nothing I can read. I'm going to give it a try though.

Comment: How about messaging the directors of the motion graphic vids you like and ask them if they would recommend a book?

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'll try. Thanks. Best answer so far. Sorry that I can't give you any credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

Zettt please check out a site called GreyScaleGorilla.com he covers this sort of, blog esq style bridging the knowledge between those beginners and the mograph world.  He is super helpful, and a great guy...also check out his forums as well as many mograph replated questions have been asked and answered there as well

GreyScaleGorilla.com

Answer (score 0):

Googling may have been a better place to start rather than Stack. There's a wealth of information out there...doing a cursory "motion graphics" search yielded this link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/25/the-ultimate-motion-graphics-tutorials-round-up/ on the first page. Adding "totorials" to the search string would have further refined the query. I'd recommend checking out the Stack FAQ about appropriate questions...this one is a little to broad and may get deleted. You may need to focus your question a little, depending on what you want to know.

Comment: That wasn't what I've been asking for. If I wanted to watch videos, I would have watched videos, but because I found these tutorials already and didn't find anything else, I figured I could ask "the pros" to get an answer.